# SAS compress: keep numbers before |

Tags: sas, compression

So one of my variables was coded in a messy mix of numeric values, texts, parenthesis and so on. I actually only need to extract the numeric values which are recorded as 12345 (for example, not limited to a specific number of digits, i mean it could be a n-k-digit to n-digit) followed by || and then description that might also contain some numeric values. So when I applied SAS compress funtion newvar = compress(oldvar, '', 'a'), the newvar extracted ALL the numbers from the oldvar. Thus it looks like 12345|||(789)|| etc. The number of '|' sign (which is control character to indicate line breaks etc.?) varies though.

I only need to extract the first numeric values before the '|' sign. Any help please?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post sample data and indicate what you have, want and what you've tried. The function for parsing text based on a delimiter should be SCAN(), but I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the SCAN() function to extract the values. It will result in a character value and converting to a numeric should be straightforward.

```
new_var = input(scan(old_var, 1, "|"), best12.);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
substr("12345||45||89||...",1,find("|","12345||45||89||...",1)-1)
```

Comment: Hi @Gaurav-taneja,
Thanks for your suggestion. If I understand correctly, the SAS code should look like:

new_var=substr(newvar,1,find("|",newvar,1)-1)

Right? I tried this but it didn't work :(